# I am trying filter data category wise

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

In that i am used two table `category(category_id, category_name)`
and second `sub_category(sub_category_id, category_id, sub_category_title, sub_category_description, image, R_price, M_price, L_price, status)`. 
I am trying to display the image, price, title when category_id is matched form sub_category table.
But It can not perform correctly

**Model**

```
function getid($id)
{
    $this->db->select('sub_category_id, category.category_name, sub_category_title, sub_category_description, image, R_price, M_price, L_price, status');
    $this->db->from('sub_category,category');
//  $this->db->join('category',' category.category_id = sub_category.category_id');
    $this->db->where('sub_category.category_id = category.category_id');
    $this->db->where('category.category_name = ',$id);
    $qry1 = $this->db->get();
    return $qry1->result_array();
}
```

Controller

```
public function product_grid()
    {
        $id= $this->input->post('dataid');
        echo 'Data-Id is form controller: '.$id ; 
        $data['rs'] = $this->PizzaUp_User_model->getid($id);
        $data['res'] = $this->PizzaUp_User_model->select('category');
        $this->load->view('product_grid',$data);
    }
```

Comment: replace `$this->db->where('category.category_name = ',$id);` with `$this->db->where('category.category_id = ',$id);`... you are comparing `category id` with `category name`

Comment: But i can allready join this table so i don't think it can be perform

Comment: @VidhiPatel, But try once what Nishant has said.

Comment: @VidhiPatel its a simple logic, you **can not** compare name field with id field, this way you won't get the results at all. if you are facing any problem comparing with id then do post your question here with the error you get.. SO people are always ready to help.. thx

Comment: @NishantSolanki ,@Shaunak Shukla thx for helping me but it is also not work perfectly

Comment: @VidhiPatel what do you mean by **not working perfectly??**, can you elaborate your problem??

Comment: @NishantSolanki I am Trying to filtering data of category wise

Answer (score 0):

> display the image, price, title form sub_category table.so here don`t need to join category table
>
> get subcategory details using category id

```
function getid($id)
{
    $this->db->select('sub_category_id,sub_category_title,sub_category_description, image, R_price, M_price, L_price, status');
        $this->db->from('sub_category');
        $this->db->where('sub_category.category_id',$id);
        $qry1 = $this->db->get();
        return $qry1->result_array();
}
```

Comment: there is a typo mistake in your answer.. `$this->db->where('category.category_id = ',$id);` should be `$this->db->where('sub_category.category_id = ',$id);`

Answer (score 0):

@Vidhi Patel Try simple join please , and use small alias if you don't want to confuse yourself

```
function getid($id)
{
    $this->db->select('sc.*, c.category_id');
    $this->db->from('sub_category as sc');
    $this->db->join('category as c','c.category_id = sc.category_id','LEFT');
    $this->db->where('sc.category_id',$id);
    $qry1 = $this->db->get();

    if ($qry1->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $qry1->result_array();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what's this ?? 
$data['res'] = $this->PizzaUp_User_model->select('category');

Comment: @Vidhi Patel , what's that calling ? select function  ? . because select is method of db if you know that . we use select in model for selecting a records from table , so you have to change that name .

Comment: i fatch the catagegory_name from category table so i can use this line.. bcz i fatch category_name dynamically

Comment: is that affect to your subcategory filter ?

Comment: can you discuss at this link https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147056/query-cod

Comment: then what i can do that all functionallity can be perform

Comment: if i want this link i need have 20 reputation but i only have 11 reputation so i can't see this link

Comment: you can also fetch category_name from my model function just . use alias of category table like c.category_name in select field

Comment: you also get category name you don't want to fetch category_name again

Comment: i do like that at first time it also don't filter my data

Comment: but my function will do just query your result and try on mysql please